# Find Library Location of Loaded Namespace

Tags: r

I'm looking to fetch what would be the `lib.loc` argument to `library` or `loadNamespace`, from a currently loaded namespace.

For attached packages this is relatively straightforward:

```
path.package("stats")  # get library location of loaded stats package
```

However, for a non-attached loaded namespace, the best I can come up with is:

```
getNamespace(x)[[".__NAMESPACE__"]][["path"]]
```

which happens to work on my R version, but has absolutely no guarantee of working in the future.  I could also temporarily attach the package to use `path.package`, but that would potentially trigger attach hooks and I'd prefer to avoid that.

Anyone know of an equivalent to `path.package` for loaded but not attached namespaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `find.package` :

> it returns path to the locations where the given packages are found.  If **lib.loc is NULL, then loaded namespaces are searched before the libraries**.